# How to iterate a mongo query through a for loop

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What I'm trying to achieve is the following which doesn't work:

```
var names = ["MATT", "GABE", "SAM"];
var students = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  students[i] = Programs.find({ CampYear: 2016, 'Teachers.Week1.Sunday': names[i] }).fetch();
  }
```

I would expect that it would return an array of student names for each iteration, but I keep getting an empty array when the array should have names.

If I remove the for loop and just do:

```
students[0] = Programs.find({ CampYear: 2016, 'Teachers.Week1.Sunday': listOfSundayTeacherNames[2] }).fetch();
```

It will return the student name(s) expected. Is a for-loop the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For whatever reason the for-loop won't work, but using a .map will.

```
 var names = _.map(names, function(num){ return Programs.find({ CampYear: 2016), 'Teachers.Week1.Sunday': num }).fetch(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

A much better approach would be to use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator with your query:

```
var students = Programs.find({ 
    'CampYear': 2016, 
    'Teachers.Week1.Sunday': { '$in': names } 
}).fetch();
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with $in. But what I was after was the organization of using an iterator. With $in, it just returns all the documents in one array, in other words, I can't tell which documents went with what name. With the iterator, I'm getting sub arrays under each name, which is what I needed because I needed to organize an output in that way.